# PHP/MYSQLI: mysqli_query fails in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

First off, I'm a total noob in mysql(i) language and know a little more than the basics of PHP.

Note: I do not manage or own / have access to the server on which the webpage currently is hosted. I can however access the phpMyAdmin page.

That said, I've got a webpage on which I am trying out some stuff. Right now I'm trying to make a log-in page linked to a database.

Now, behold the code:

```
$mysql_host = "localhost";
$mysql_user = "my_user";
$mysql_database = "my_database";
$mysql_password = "my_password";

$table = "my_tablename";

// Create connection 
$con=mysqli_connect($mysql_host,$mysql_user,$mysql_password,$mysql_database); 

// Check connection 
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con)) { 
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error(); 
}

// sending query
$result = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM my_tablename");
if (!$result) {
    echo "Query to show fields from table failed! :-(";
}
```

Now, here comes the actual problem. As soon as I launch the page it will give me my "Query to show fields from table failed!" error message. But when I enter the same query on the phpMyAdmin 'SQL' tab, I get the wanted results. How come the webpage gives me an error, while the phpMyAdmin gives me the results, and, how do I solve it?

Comment: mysqli extension is slightly different from the old mysql. It must have the link identifier in procedural coding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use correct syntax:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM my_tablename");
```

You forgot to link current mysqli connection. First parameter is link - which mysqli connection you want to use (good for multiple conns) and then the second is your query.

Comment: Ah! I thought, because I already made the connection at the beginning of the script, and knowing the connection closes at the end of a script, it would work like that. But, how can I see if the query fails, since the `$result` would be partially `true` due to the connection passing?

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean. It worked on old mysql, where connection links weren't needed.

Comment: I mean, the `!$result` will be `false`, since the `$con` part passes. How can I check if the `"SELECT * FROM my_tablename"` passes as well?

Comment: For debugging it is used `mysqli_query(...) or die ('Query failed');`. But if you want to only check your query, you need to link which connection you want to use because, if you have 2 different connections, in one conn it may return `true` and in second it may return `false`.

Comment: When I use `mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM my_tablename")or die("Failed");`, it says "Failed" and won't load the rest of the php / html on the page (I know why that is). Is there no way if I can see if it gives a `true` or `false`, or any other output?

Comment: You need to link your connection. All this answer is about linking your connection. You can see that too here - http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_query.asp

Comment: Marking this answer as the solution, because it did get a correct solution for my question.